# My arguments do not work in the method because of an issue with the generics

Tags: java, generics

I have been stumped on this one for a few days now and I'm wondering how I can get around this issue I'm having. My code is essentially as follows:

```
public class AClass<T extends BClass> {
    public void aMethod(final T obj) {
        SdkClass.sdkMethod(obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to compile I get the error from line 3:

```
The method sdkMethod(Class<T>) in the type SdkClass is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends BClass>)
```

It's important to note that I can't modify the method or class on line 3 since it's from an SDK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

The method signature is `SdkClass.sdkMethod(Class<T>)`

Comment: Please share the signature of `SdkClass.sdkMethod()`

Comment: It's `SdkClass.sdkMethod(Class<T>)`

Comment: @MaxStevens: "The method signature is SdkClass.sdkMethod(Class<T>)" And where does that `T` come from if `sdkMethod` is a static method? Is it a generic method with `T` declared on the method?